# Hibernate and rownum in inner query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have the following query in oracle that I want to use in hibernate but cannot work out how to use the rownum variable in an inner query.  The query is as follows:

```
select emp.prof_key, emp.prof_display_name
from empinst.emp emp
where emp.prof_key IN (select x.object_key
                   from (select event.object_key as object_key
                         from empinst.eventlog event
                         where event.event_name = 'profiles.created'
                         and event.event_source = 'Profiles'
                         order by event.created desc) x
                   where rownum <= 10)
```

The only way that I can work out how to do it is to break the query into two parts but I assume there must be a more efficient way to do it in hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Michael.

Comment: Why do you want to restrict the sub-query?  There is (usually) not much of a relationship between the number of rows returned in the sub-query and the number of rows in the actual result set.

Comment: It seems pointless to arbitrarily pick the first 10 rows from eventlog. Is the intention to do some kind of random sampling? Also, what do you mean by "rownum variable"? You've used a literal value, are you asking how to use a bind variable there instead?

Comment: The rownum variable is a reserved word in oracle that returns the row number and is used for pagination.  The reason I only want to show ten rows is because I want to see the most recent 10 event log records.  The number of 10 is arbitary, but I only want to see the most x records.  The table itself can contain 10,000's of records...  by running the query without the inner query and rownum the query returns in about 24 seconds, with the inner query it returns in 0.3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

your query will not filter the 10 most recent records. It will return 10 **random** records (Random as in unreliable order) since there is no ORDER BY clause.

I'm not familiar with the limitations of hibernate but as with all limiting tools I'm pretty sure you can work around them with a well-thought view.

For example, this view will contain a rank column you can use to filter the 10 most recent record for any combination of `(event_name, event_source)` based on an ordering column `event_date`:

```
CREATE VIEW eventlog_rank_v AS 
SELECT e.*, 
       row_number() OVER (PARTYTION BY e.event_name, 
                                       e.event_source 
                          ORDER BY e.event_date DESC) event_rank
  FROM empinst.eventlog e;
```

Comment: Hello, well spotted!  The order by was missing from the query (I pulled it out of hibernate and started playing with it in sqldev to fix it up and missed the order by statement.  I have edited the original question to show it with the order by.

Comment: @Michael: your query still needs some fixing: the `ORDER BY` clause is evaluated *after* the `WHERE` clause. Basically your query means SELECT 10 rows **randomly**, then `ORDER BY event.created`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735614/how-to-select-n-rows/1735644#1735644 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909923/more-elegant-sql/909963#909963 for examples of TOP-N queries

Comment: You are correct.  I looked at the query more closely and the links you supplied and it appeared that the query was doing exactly as you described.  I have changed it again as I can now see it is generating the correct data.